# When writing a gem, how bad practice is to include its module by default?

Tags: ruby, include, rubygems

When writing a Ruby library, when is it acceptable practice to do this in one file?

```
module MyLib
  # some definitions
end

include MyLib
```

I found that usually, one has to

```
require 'some_gem'
```

first, and then

```
include SomeGem
```

But I wonder, in some simpler cases, when you just want to add a bit of funcionality to the core, would it be O.K. to include the main module by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a bad practice. If you include it, then you are choosing how people can use it. You are making the decision for them that they want it included in the global namespace. That isn't your decision to make, be a good Ruby citizen, don't change your user's environments. Allow them to choose how they want to use the code.

Comment: I guess I'll abide by what you say. I have bad feelings about it myself, that's why I'm asking. But, just out of curiosity, are there any exceptions to this rule? (It's quite possible that there are no exceptions, but I'd like to hear others say somthing on this.)

Comment: The only exception I can think of would be if you put the include in another file, then if they wanted that included, they could require that file instead. You'd have to be careful to keep any useful stuff out of there, so that all it does is load the lib and then include the file. Remember when you include something at the top level, you're affecting `Object`, which almost everything inherits from.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my library accordingly. Now, how about the case when gem A uses gem B, in order to use it does "require 'b'; include B" and therefore "require 'a'" ends up polluting the requirer's space with B module? I have not found the way to prevent this (B is my custom duck typing library), so I am thinking about putting up with it.

Comment: A can do that if A wants to, the point is that B doesn't make that decision for A. Don't try to prevent A from including B, for the same reason that B shouldn't include itself at the top level, because you want to allow them to choose how they want to use the code.

Comment: Thanks, that's what my colleague told me, too.

Answer (score 2):

The require 'some_gem' / include SomeGem combo is something found mostly in scripts (as opposed to libraries). It is important, in libraries, to keep the namespaces separate -- this is the whole point of having namespaces in the first place.